# What is the difference between a probability measure and a measure induced by a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, terminology

Apparently, there are two different measures when we talk about random variables. There's the [probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure), often denoted as $\mathbb{P}$, which is a function from the event space $\mathcal{F}$ to $[0, 1]$, that is, $\mathbb{P}: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow [0, 1]$. The notion of a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$, apparently,  makes sense even before defining a random variable. However, apparently, there's also another measure which is induced by the random variable $X: (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, after we defined it, where $\Omega$ is the sample space. This measure induced by $X$ should be defined on $\mathbb{R}$. What does this mean? Does this mean that the induced measure has domain or codomain $\mathbb{R}$?

What is the rigorous definition of this measure induced by $X$? What's the difference between the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ and the measure induced by $X$? What's the intuition behind this measure induced by a random variable $X$?

Comment: Well, as far as I know, measure induced by a random variable is just a *pushforward* measure for $\mathbb{P}$ under a map defined by $X$. That is you measure a set in the target space by taking the preimage and measuring it in source space. Since the random variable is a measurable map from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$ it fits into this picture nicely. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure

Comment: @GregoryG Feel free to provide a formal answer to my questions. I would appreciate if you can define all the terms you use, because I have no background in measure theory, pushforward measure, etc.

Comment: $P$ defines a measure on $\Omega$. A random variable $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ (combined with $P$) induces a measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ according to $\mu A = P\{\omega | X(\omega) \in A\}$.

Comment: @copper.hat What is $\Omega$ in your case? In my case, I am defining a random variable from the probability space and not from the sample space.

Comment: @nbro: A probability has an associated sample space $\Omega$ and an allowable collection of events, in your case ${\cal F}$. ${\cal F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @copper.hat You mean a probability space (and not a probability)?

Comment: I mean the function $P$. A measure space has an underlying set and a collection of measurable subsets on which $P$ is defined (a $\sigma$-algebra). Wikipedia is not very precise. A marginally better page is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space.

Comment: @copper.hat I thought that the probability measure is independent of the measurable space (i.e. sample space + event space) and that a measurable space equipped with a probability measure is a measure space (more specifically, a probability space).

Comment: Sorry, are you asking about definitions or the induced measures? There are three things here, an underlying measure space, a probability measure on this space and a random variable on the measure space. The combination of a real valued random variable and a probability measure on the same underlying space induces a measure on the range of the random variable.

Comment: @copper.hat My main question is about the measure induced by the random variable. However, you're using certain terms and expressions, which are a little bit inconsistent with my knowledge, that's why I also asked about the definitions in my comment above. Anyway, you did not answer my question above about the definition of a random variable. You defined it as $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where I assumed that $\Omega$ is the sample space (while I had used a different definition). Furthermore, your definition of the induced measure is also not very clear, because you do not define $X$.

Comment: Replace $X$ by $f$ or whatever way you want.

Comment: @copper.hat And what is $A$ in $\mu A$? Anyway, given your definition above, it's not clear the difference between this $\mu$ and $\mathbb{P}$. It seems like you define this induced measure as a function of the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ (which you only denote by $P$).

Comment: Like I said, $\mu$ induces a measure on the reals, so $A$ is a subset of the reals.

Comment: One last comment, as I am finding this interaction a bit frustration for many reasons. Underlying everything in this discussion is a sample space $\Omega$. There is a probablility measure $P$ (or whatever symbol you care to type, these are comments to help, not precision instructions) that is defined on certain subsets of $\Omega$ and a random variable is a real valued function defined on $\Omega$. The induced measure is a measure on the reals induced by the combination of $P$ and the random variable. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Given a random variable $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, we get a new probability measure by considering the pushforward measure (= induced measure by $X$ on $\mathbb{P}$)

$$\mathbb{P}_X: \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})\to [0,1]$$

defined by
$$\mathbb{P}_X(A) := \mathbb{P}(\{X \in A\}) = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(A))$$

for a Borel set $A \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

The probability measure $\mathbb{P}_X$ is commonly referred to as the distribution of $X$.

---

**Example**: Consider the probability measure

$$\mu: \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}) \to [0,1]: A \mapsto \int_A \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-x^2/2) \lambda(dx)$$

If $X$ is a random variable on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ such that $\mu = \mathbb{P}_X$, then we say that $X$ is standard normally distributed and we write $X \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: Ok, but what's the induced measure, in your answer? I think you forgot to make it explicit. Also, what does the notations $\{X \in A\}$ and $X^{-1}(A)$ mean? Wasn't $X$ the random variable?

Comment: The induces measure is what I denoted with $\mathbb{P}_X$. This is a measure on the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$. And $X^{-1}(A)$ and $\{X \in A\}$ are the same thing. By definition, the preimage $X^{-1}(A)$ is the set $\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \in A\}$, i.e. all samples in the sample space that get mapped to $A$ by $X$. A random variable is a function!!

Comment: I don't get why we define the random variable on a probability space with $\mathbb{P}$ and then we define this new probability measure (the induced probability measure $\mathbb{P}_X$). When do we use (or need) one over the other?

Comment: Example: Suppose you have a population $\Omega$ of people and $X$ is the random variable that assigns a person to its length in meter. What is the probability that someone in this population is larger than 1.5meter? This is exactly $\mathbb{P}\{X \geq 1.5\}= \mathbb{P}_X([1.5, + \infty[)$. So if we know the measure $\mathbb{P}_X$, we can answer this question. In this case, there is reason to believe that $X$ will follow a normal distribution, so $\mathbb{P}_X$ is known and we can answer the question without even knowing explicitely what $X$ is!

Comment: But you're telling me that $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{P}_X$ are equivalent, so why do we need both? Why not simply using $\mathbb{P}$?

Comment: They are not equivalent. If you know $\mathbb{P}$, you know $\mathbb{P}_X$, but not conversely. There is no way to determine what $\mathbb{P}$ is given the random variable $X$ and its induces measure $\mathbb{P}_X$.

Comment: In statistics, for example, we cannot measure every person if our population is too large. But if we know how $X$ is distributed (i.e. what $\mathbb{P}_X$) is, we can still answer questions like what is the probability that someone is larger than 1.5m etc.